# viewModelScope.launch{} runs only first time

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt, activity-lifecycle, coroutinescope

I came across an issue while building my live app.

**Example 1** shows the situation when I open my main activity for the first time, the viewModelScope.launch
in my MainActivityViewModel works as expected, however when I open the second activity and close the current activity (main activity) and then open the main activity again the viewModelScope.launch does not work because the viewModelScope is not active.

**Example 2** shows the situation when I open my main activity for the first time, the viewModelScope.launch
in my MainActivityViewModel works as expected, however when I open the second activity and NOT close the current activity (main activity) and then open the main activity again the viewModelScope.launch continues with the previous work and also starts a new work.

I am not sure if that is somehow related to this issue, however, I am using **Dagger-Hilt** for dependency injection.

My goal here is to find out how to launch the viewModelScope.launch every time when I open my main activity and what causing the issue (Example 1).

Secondly, find out how to stop the viewModelScope.launch (Example 2) when I am opening the second activity without closing the current activity (main activity).

**Example 1 - Activity (Java)**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MainActivityViewModel viewModel;
...
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);

viewModel.testOneViewModelScopeMA();

binding.btnSecondActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startSecondActivityIntentWithFinishCurrentActivity(MainActivity.this);
//                startSecondActivityIntentWithOutFinishCurrentActivity(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
...

private void startSecondActivityIntentWithFinishCurrentActivity(Context _context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(_context, SecondActivity.class);
    _context.startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**Example 1 - ViewModel (Kotlin)**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainActivityRepository: MainActivityRepository,
    @IoDispatcher private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    @MainDispatcher private val mainDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    @DefaultDispatcher private val defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {
...

fun testOneViewModelScopeMA() {
    Timber.d("-> testOneViewModelScope, " +
            "\nviewModelScope is active: ${viewModelScope.isActive}")
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            var count = 0
            while (true) {
                delay(1000L)
                count += 1
                Timber.d(
                    "-> testOneViewModelScope, " +
                            "\nviewModelScope is active: ${viewModelScope.isActive} " +
                            "\noutput: $count "
                )
            }

        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            Timber.e(
                "-> testOneViewModelScope, " +
                        "\nviewModelScope is active: ${viewModelScope.isActive} " +
                        "\nCancellationException: \n${e.localizedMessage}"
            )
            throw e
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Timber.e(
                "-> testOneViewModelScope, " +
                        "\nviewModelScope is active: ${viewModelScope.isActive} " +
                        "\nException: \n${ex.localizedMessage}"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - Activity (Java)**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MainActivityViewModel viewModel;
...
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);

viewModel.testOneViewModelScopeMA();

binding.btnSecondActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // startSecondActivityIntentWithFinishCurrentActivity(MainActivity.this);
          startSecondActivityIntentWithOutFinishCurrentActivity(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
...

   private void startSecondActivityIntentWithOutFinishCurrentActivity(Context _context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(_context, SecondActivity.class);
        _context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Example 2 - ViewModel (Kotlin) - the same as Example 1 ViewModel**

Answer (score 0):

Let separate your issues

1. You want to launch a coroutine in ActivityA, every time you open it (newly created and/or go back from other activities). If these, put a call to your view model in [ActivityA#onResume](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onresume). Because `Activity#onCreate` is called only one time when the your application creates the activity
2. You want to cancel your coroutine in Activity A, when you leave it to navigate to other activities.

- Add a supervisor job to the coroutine's launch
- In ActivityA's [onPause](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onpause) call your view model to cancel the supervisor job

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

**Example 1,**

After a lot of testing I find out that the issue is *Dagger-Hilt related*, however, I still do not know how to solve it.

**Example 2,**

A few days ago I added a Job to the View Model: *viewModelScope.launch(cancelableViewModelJob)* and cancel the job in Activity onPause. However, that creates a new challenge. The challenge is that when the phone goes to sleep then the Job is canceled also.

Comment: Example 1: Please describle your issue

Comment: Example 2: Yes, of course, because when the phone goes to sleep, your activity will go to background, and onPause and onStop will be called (same as when you go to other activities). I wonder what your job does that you need it to run whenever an activity is in background state.

Comment: **Situation:**
You open a Main Activity for the first time, in onCreate the viewModel.testOneViewModelScopeMA() starts. Then you open Second Activity by Intend and finish() the Main Activity. After that, you open Main Activity by Intent again and finish() the Second Activity.

**Dagger-Hilt solution:**
When you open Main Activity for the first time everything works ok, however, when you open the Main Activity from the Second Activity the viewModelScope is not active and does nothing.

**Non-Dagger-Hilt solution:**
Everything works ok as expected.

Comment: No, If you finish MainActivity then re-open by launch an intent from SecondActivity. The system will create a brand new `MainActivity` and every think will work as expected

Comment: "I wonder what your job does"

For instance, the driver downloads data for delivery and during the time the phone goes to sleep for whatever reason. When you cancel the job then the driver has to start again to download the data.

Comment: "The system will create a brand new MainActivity"

Yes, I agree that is why I do not understand why the Dagger-Hilt solution does not work and ask this question. I did a lot of testing before I post it this question.

Comment: For that kind of task, think about using `work-manager`

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue @DevPeter?  I've found myself with the same problem, were Hilt seems to halt the `viewModelScope` collection in my app and I don't know how to stop that.  Everything works fine without the Hilt injection.  I'm in desperate need for a solution!

Comment: On a second note @DevPeter, I was able to solve my problem where the `viewModelScope` was not catching the repository updates when I backed from destinationB, and into destinationA.